# Adding new key/values to object not saved after mongo query returned

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a function that needs to do 2 set of queries, one to get facility info, and another to get information about user at that facility.
Once both queries are done, I send the facility info, with user info appended to each user record to the front end.

Problem:
The appended info is not being saved as expected.

code:

```
app.get(
  async (req, res) => {
    const facilityInfo = await Facility.findOne({ admins: req.user.username })
    for (let i = 0; i < facilityInfo.memberships.length; i++){
      facilityInfo.memberships[i].info = await User.findOne({username: facilityInfo.memberships[i].username})
    }
    console.log(facilityInfo)
    res.status(200).send(facilityInfo);
  }
);
```

the log statement never returns the infomation retrived in the second query unless I specifically log facilityInfo.memberships[0].info, at which point it does. The 'info' key does not natively get returned when in the document initially, it's only created when the second query executes.

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the records from the database, you update these records in the code, but you do not send the updated records to the database.

```
app.get(
    async (req, res) => {
        const facilityInfo = await Facility.findOne({ admins: req.user.username })
        for (let i = 0; i < facilityInfo.memberships.length; i++) {
            facilityInfo.memberships[i].info = await User.findOne({ username: facilityInfo.memberships[i].username })
        }
        // Update the data
        await facilityInfo.save();
        
        console.log(facilityInfo)
        res.status(200).send(facilityInfo);
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to save the data, but append the data together.  Admittedly, this is a relational query between the two collections, which I realize isn't great to do with a noSQL database.  If I log facilityInfo.memberships, I get none of the returned details, If I log facilityInfo[i].memberships.info it's appended correctly.  My workaround was to use lodash merge().